# Is there any limit to filesize while downloading through browser over http

Tags: javascript, browser, filesystems, azure-cdn

I am trying to download more than 10 GB of files over HTTP through the browser. While is accessed from CDN.

I am observing intermittent behavior, at times 2GB file downloads are failing but sometimes able to download up to 12 GB files successfully.

What is the maximum limit of file size that can be downloaded through the browser?

Is it a browser problem or client-side network problem or CDN problem on the server-side?

Comment: The only limit on the client-side is the client computer memory otherwise the issue is usually from the server where the stream times out.

Comment: As I am using CDN to get the content from Azure Verizon CDN, it shouldn't have any timeout.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "Maximum" File size while transferring through HTTP. But sometimes it could be the browser's problem. It could also be a server-side problem as well.
But there is no actual maximum size.

Comment: I am getting this issue in Chrome, Firefox and Edge browsers. Haven't tried in any other browser.

Comment: Then it must be a server side issue if all the browsers are showing the same issue. @ChandrashekarH.L

Answer (score 0):

http : no maximumsize so network or brower problem